# How i get callback notification while BTC received to wallet

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core-development

i installed bit coin core in my Windows machine [test-net] .i implemented a C#.net application using Bitcoin RPC command like generate address , transfer BTC to one address to another address. It working great.

My question is, how can I get a notification once an address that I generated receives a payment? How can I get a notification when the payment is confirmed?

Any help / guidance would be helpful.

[image: Test net bitcoin core]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use ZeroMQ for that purpose see [Bitcoin/zmq](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/zmq.md) once you receive a transaction you can get a notification.

Bitcoin/zmq doesn't tell you if some transaction confirmations changed, so you can check transaction confirmations manually by calling `getrawtransaction`

You can use walletnotfiy as well

```
walletnotify=/bin/curl http://127.0.0.1/receive.php?trx=%s
```

Comment: They can also use the walletnotify option

Comment: Thanks @Adam i resolved issue using wallet notify -> walletnotify=curl http://123.95.66.172/Notify/walletnotiy?txnid=%s in bitcoin config file . i implemented  a simple mvc.net application